# pass arguments to git post-receive hooks

Tags: git

As mentioned https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks, git post-receive hook doesn't take any arguments. I want to pass an one/multiple arguments to the post-receive script.

`git push origin <branch_name> <arg1> <arg2> ...`

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

No: this is literally impossible in most cases, because your Git runs an `ssh` or similar transport agent, which connects to the host on which `origin`'s Git lives, and fires up a different (unrelated by program invocation ancestry) Git on that machine, which then runs all the receive processing.  For security reasons, these transport agents limit the "attack surface area", cleaning out side channel information.

What this boils down to is that you can only supply "arguments" by smuggling them inside the pushed *data*.  What does get pushed—i.e., the data—are new commits and any objects referenced from those commits, and reference names (mostly branch and/or tag names).

Note that a post-receive hook could take a tag name where the tag points to a standalone commit or blob that contains the arguments, extract those arguments, then delete that tag.  You would still have to take some care to handle cases where many individual sources are `git push`-ing at approximately the same time, delivering many objects and references, including multiple tags with multiple arguments, causing multiple simultaneous post-receive script runs.  Git locks itself against its own updates while running pre-receive and update hooks, but the post-receive hook is run after releasing these locks.